# How to Access a List within a List in linear Time and Create Indeterminate Numbers of Objects

Tags: python, oop

In Python, I'm currently working on a project. I am storing lines from a file as a list. In these lines, I want to delimit the strings by spaces and store the individual words from the line in an object.

Each line contains three "words" spaced apart. I want to store each word as an element in a class object. Since I do not know how many lines the user may have in the input file, these objects will be created in an indeterminate amount.

When I run through the list of lines and "split" them, I get a list within a list. I do not know what to do with the data in that form (without using a for-loop within a for-loop), I'm stuck here.

I already have the object class created with three fields and methods to access those fields. However, I do not know how to access the "list within a list" (in linear time) and delimit the words and easily and quickly create a new object with the words as the parameters.

If anyone could give me advice on where to go from here, I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, word1, word2, word3):
        # your initialisation code here

for line in list_of_lines:
    words = line.split()
    assert len(words) == 3
    an_object = MyClass(*words)
    do_something_with(an_object)
```

**Update** in response to comment:

To get a list of MyClass objects, one for each line in your input file:

```
with open("my_input_file.txt") as f:
    the_list = [MyClass(*line.split()) for line in f]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I got a weird output when  Any suggestions? http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/845/pythonhelp.png/

Comment: @LearningPython: Your "weird ouptut" (`__main__.Edge instance at some_hex_address`) results from your code doing `print an_object`. Your `Edge` class has not defined a `__str__` or `__repr__` method, so you get the default result -- it tells you that `an_object` refers to an instance of your `Edge` class which is located in memory at the given address. If you want to know how to get a non-default non-"weird" result from `print an_object`, ask a separate question; you will need to show the code of your `Edge` class.

Comment: Okay, I figured out how to fix it / added a string method. How do I add an indefinite amount of objects? Is that even possible since the names have to be hard-coded?

Comment: @LearningPython: If you mean that there are an indefinite number of objects because you have an indefinite number of data lines: append each object to a list (as I said in a comment on the answer by @Orjanp) ... then only the list needs to have a name. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why split them before use? Why not split the line when you need it?

Some pseudo codeish

```
for each line in list
    items = line split
    object(items)
```

Comment: How do you create multiple objects rather than just one hard-coded object? I apologize if that's a starter question, though I am new to object-oriented design.

Comment: @LearningPython: @Orjanp's answer is pseudocode -- don't take it as literal executable-immediately code. In any case: I see no "one hard-coded object" anywhere. The general thrust of @Orjanp's pseudocode (and mine) is that you create an Edge instance from each line. Each instance is distinct from all others, even if the 3 "words" used to create them are identical. It is up to you to do something useful with each instance, like (for example) append it to a list ...